Unity Game in Google Play Console Problem with AndroidManifest.xml, android:exported
I'm trying to put a 2D Game made in unity into the google play store. Never done it before and when I'm trying to upload the app bundle in google play console, I get the error,
You have uploaded an APK or an Android App Bundle that includes an activity, an activity alias, a service, or a broadcast receiver with an intent filter that does not have the 'android
' property set. This file cannot be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported
This is my androidmanifest.xml. First time I've heard of it and therefore only added the line android:exported="false".
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

I have no idea what the problem is and how to change it, I looked up tutorials and other projects on github, but they dont seem to have similar lines.
Please help me if you have ideas what the problem might be.
I tried comparing with apps on github, asked chat gpt and looked into several tutorials, pages by unity and android developers and similar questions on stack overflow (either didnt get it or its a newer problem)

You need to set android:exported="true"
or don't use AndroidManifest at all if you're on a newer version of Unity.

I tried both ways, but will still get the same error. Would true need more lines of code or just the change from false to true?

My solution: I used Unity 2020. Android 12 was released in 2021, so I tried to make a project in Unity 2022 and the Problem wasnt there anymore.
